# How to Show correctly twitter blockquotes in Android Webview

Tags: android, twitter, webview

I have the following code

```
     <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
     <p dir="ltr" lang="en"><a href="https://twitter.com
    /MichaelEssien">@MichaelEssien</a> come to Panathinaikos,ask
    <a href="https://twitter.com/DjibrilCisse">@DjibrilCisse</a>
    for references;)
    </p>
     Christos Kitsakis (@ChrisKitsakis) <a href="https://twitter.com
/ChrisKitsakis/status/597031669544136704">May 9, 2015</a>
   </blockquote>
<script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and i put it with JavaScript Interface in a web view.
but it doesn't show correctly in Android Web view.

What should i do?